# I don't understand a valgrind error I'm getting

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

```
==3275== Invalid read of size 8
==3275==    at 0x53D006E: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1362)
==3275==    by 0x53C5C6C: fwrite (iofwrite.c:45)
==3275==    by 0x4EE4C9D: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==3275==    by 0x4EE4FA6: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==3275==    by 0x401D4C: main (q2.cc:45)
==3275==  Address 0x5a254b8 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 43 free'd
==3275==    at 0x4C2A4BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3275==    by 0x4EF27BF: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==3275==    by 0x40197D: read(std::istream&, character&) (utf8char.cc:16)
==3275==    by 0x401B6C: main (q2.cc:27)
```

This is the relevant code:

```
infile = new ifstream(argv[1]);
character CurrChar;
character &UTF = CurrChar;
```

where character is a structure that holds 4 bytes. I don't think it's relevant.

`q2.cc:27 utfchar = read(*infile, UTF)`

```
q2.cc:44   catch (UTF8err err) {
q2.cc:45         cout << err.msg << ends;
q2.cc:46         ....
```

where err is :

```
struct UTF8err {              // exception
  const char *msg;`
  UTF8err( const char *msg ) : msg( msg ) {}
};
```

`utf8char.cc:16 string pad = " : invalid padding";`

Comment: Who or what manages the lifetime of the data that `msg` points to? It seems you've messed that up. Where's the code that constructs a `UTF8err`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm just doing `string range = " : invalid range";` and then `throw UTF8err(range.c_str());` into main.

Comment: Well that obviously won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `c_str`, the result is valid so long as the string isn't modified or destroyed. But when you throw, the stack is unwound, destroying the string. So the pointer points to something that no longer exists.

Perhaps change the type of `msg` from `const char*` to `std::string`. Perhaps make the string `static`. Perhaps make the `UTF8err` class manage its own memory.